# XSLT string replace

Tags: xslt, xpath, replace, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

I don't really know XSL but I need to fix this code, I have reduced it to make it simpler.
I am getting this error

> Invalid XSLT/XPath function

on this line

```
<xsl:variable name="text" select="replace($text,'a','b')"/>
```

This is the XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:inm="http://www.inmagic.com/webpublisher/query" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="mos">
        <xsl:apply-templates />

        <xsl:for-each select="mosObj">
          'Notes or subject' 
           <xsl:call-template
                name="rem-html">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="SBS_ABSTRACT" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="rem-html">
        <xsl:param name="text" />
        <xsl:variable name="text" select="replace($text, 'a', 'b')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: Please note that the `replace()` function is available from XPath 2.0 (and therefore XSLT 2.0) onward and supports regular expressions replacements.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

`replace` isn't available for XSLT 1.0.

Codesling has a [template for string-replace](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025173545/http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx) you can use as a substitute for the function:

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$text = '' or $replace = ''or not($replace)" >
            <!-- Prevent this routine from hanging -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

invoked as:

```
<xsl:variable name="newtext">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="a" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="b" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

On the other hand, if you literally only need to replace one character with another, you can call [`translate`](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_translate.html) which has a similar signature. Something like this should work fine:

```
<xsl:variable name="newtext" select="translate($text,'a','b')"/>
```

Also, note, in this example, I changed the variable name to "newtext", in XSLT variables are immutable, so you can't do the equivalent of `$foo = $foo` like you had in your original code.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but now I am getting this error:

An unknown XPath extension function was called

Comment: @aximili, sorry, got XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 confused, edited...should be good to go now.

Comment: This answer is wrong! The replace function in XSLT replaces corresponding SINGLE CHARACTERS, not the whole strings! See for example here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: @Jakub You're thinking of `translate`, not `replace`.  The `replace` function in XPath 2.0 treats its second argument as a _regular expression_ and replaces all matches of that expression with the specified replacement string (which may include `$n` references to capturing groups in the regex).  The `translate` function (in 1.0 and 2.0) is the one that does single-character-for-single-character replacements.

Comment: shouldn't the 4th line in the example usage be   `<xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'a'" />` with quotes around the a?

Comment: This solution will not be able to handle input with XML/HTML, since a `disable-output-escaping`-attribute is missing. I guess it must be added manually and if both variants are needed there has to be two templates?

Answer (score 41):

Here is the XSLT function which will work similar to the String.Replace() function of C#.

This template has the 3 Parameters as below

**text** :- your main string

**replace** :- the string which you want to replace

**by** :- the string which will reply by new string

**Below are the Template**

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
  <xsl:param name="text" />
  <xsl:param name="replace" />
  <xsl:param name="by" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
      <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

**Below sample shows how to call it**

```
<xsl:variable name="myVariable ">
  <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'This is a {old} text'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'{old}'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'New'" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

You can also refer the [below URL](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025173545/http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx) for the details.

Comment: Using xslt 1.0 This post/template worked for me while Mark Elliot's did not.

Answer (score 14):

**Note:** In case you wish to use the already-mentioned algo for cases where you need to replace huge number of instances in the source string (e.g. new lines in long text) there is *high* probability you'll end up with `StackOverflowException` because of the recursive call.

I resolved this issue thanks to **Xalan**'s (didn't look how to do it in **Saxon**) built-in Java type embedding:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan str"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
                xmlns:str="xalan://java.lang.String"
        >
...
<xsl:value-of select="str:replaceAll(
    str:new(text()),
    $search_string,
    $replace_string)"/>
...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dumb but I get: `Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'xalan://java.lang.String'.`

Comment: What is your XSLT engine?

Comment: My comment was for for most popular Java XSLT 1.0 engine Xalan (https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/), which supports direct mapping to available types inside available Java classpath; you can't apply my solution for .Net stack

Comment: @IanGrainger, you can use it with .NET by adding an `<msxsl:script>` block, which can call any .NET method, library etc. Though .NET also supports the EXSLT extension functions, so you wouldn't need to.

Comment: [exslt](http://exslt.org/) is also supported in [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/libxslt/) and therefore in all descendents [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) etc...

Comment: I was getting the exact StackOverflowException error. Thanks for your answer! A quick question, is there anyway to chain multiple replacements using replaceAll(...)?

Answer (score 13):

I keep hitting this answer. But none of them list the easiest solution for xsltproc (and probably most XSLT 1.0 processors):

1. Add the exslt strings name to the stylesheet, i.e.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

2. Then use it like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="str:replace(., ' ', '')"/>
```

Comment: The xsltproc on my computer (macOS 10.13) does NOT support the `str:replace()` function. Neither does any of the other major XSLT 1.0 processors - Xalan, Saxon 6.5 and Microsoft.

Comment: Works fine with my xsltproc for cygwin: `Using libxml 20912, libxslt 10129 and libexslt 817`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following code when your processor runs on .NET Framework *(Not supported on .NET Core or .NET 5)* or uses MSXML (as opposed to Java-based or other native processors). It uses [`msxsl:script`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxaw5z5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Make sure to add the namespace `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` to your root `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` element.

In addition, bind `outlet` to any namespace you like, for instance `xmlns:outlet = "http://my.functions"`.

```
<msxsl:script implements-prefix="outlet" language="javascript">
function replace_str(str_text,str_replace,str_by)
{
     return str_text.replace(str_replace,str_by);
}
</msxsl:script>


<xsl:variable name="newtext" select="outlet:replace_str(string(@oldstring),'me','you')" />
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dumb, but I get `prefix outlet is not defined` or `'xsl:script' cannot be a child of the 'xsl:stylesheet' element.` if I change msxsl for my prefix. I'm guessing this is some Microsoft-specific XSLT magic?

Comment: @IanGrainger, it is not `xsl:script`, but `msxsl:script`, and it has a different namespace (I've updated John's answer).

Answer (score 0):

The rouine is pretty good, however it causes my app to hang, so I needed to add the case:

```
  <xsl:when test="$text = '' or $replace = ''or not($replace)" >
    <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
    <!-- Prevent thsi routine from hanging -->
  </xsl:when>
```

before the function gets called recursively.

I got the answer from here:
[When test hanging in an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743337/when-test-hanging-in-an-infinite-loop)

Thank you!