# concat comma separated string values

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to concat all the numbers (like 1+0+1+1+1). Note the comma separated values may increase or decrease. Here is xml xsl code:

**xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="class.xsl"?>
<root><LIST>
 <ROLE>s1</ROLE>
<STATUS>yes</STATUS>
</LIST>
<LIST>
<ROLE>s1</ROLE>
<STATUS>d</STATUS>
</LIST>
<LIST>
<ROLE>Member</ROLE>
<STATUS>no</STATUS>
</LIST>
<LIST>
<ROLE>Member</ROLE>
<STATUS>no</STATUS>
</LIST>
<LIST>
<ROLE>Member</ROLE>
<STATUS>yes</STATUS>
</LIST>
</root>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/"><html>
    <h2>
<xsl:variable name="orgactcount">
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/LIST">
    <xsl:if test = "STATUS='yes'">
<xsl:value-of select="'1,'"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$orgactcount"/>
</h2></html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

orgactcount variable has 1,1, value, it has to concated like 1+1....i am trying to split all the comma separated values and then manipulation ... but i could not ...does anyone have idea

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Please elaborate a bit, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: i have updated my code. please have a look!

Comment: Can you show your current input XML document, as well as your expected output, as that would make things even clearer. Thank you.

Comment: please find the above xml code

Comment: Don't you just want to evaluate this: `count(/*/LIST[STATUS='yes'])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Edited your XSLT by adding `translate` function.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <h2>

        <xsl:variable name="orgactcount">
          <xsl:for-each select="/root/LIST">
            <xsl:if test = "STATUS='yes'">
              <xsl:value-of select="'1,'"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="formattedorgactcount" select="translate($orgactcount, ',', '+' )"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$formattedorgactcount"/>

      </h2>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Following will also helpful to you.

[XSLT string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067113/xslt-string-replace)

Comment: @ezhil way of thanking in Stackoverflow is accept the answer and vote up ...cheers...

Comment: @ezhil vote for the answer also, by clicking up arrow head..thanks