# whitespace URL in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a xslt showing no whitespace as characters.

In this case show only **%**.

**URL:**

```
http://localhost:8888/tire/details/Bridgestone/ECOPIA%EP001S/Bridgestone,ECOPIA%EP001S,195--65%R15%91H,TL,ECO,0
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">
  <xsl:param name="extractorHost" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <links>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </links>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="//x:form/x:a[@class='arrow-link forward']">
    <xsl:variable name="url" select="translate(@href, ' ', '%20')"/>
    <link href="{concat($extractorHost, $url)}" />
  </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The correct URL should be:

```
http://localhost:8888/tire/details/Bridgestone/ECOPIA%20EP001S/Bridgestone,ECOPIA%20EP001S,195--65%20R15%2091H,TL,ECO,0
```

Is it wrong XSLT formed?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: [XSLT string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067113/xslt-string-replace)

You can use already existing templates that will let you use "replace" function.

Comment: Problem in:
<xsl:variable name="newtext">
      <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@href" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="+" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="%20" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

Answer (score 2):

The XPath [`translate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) function doesn't work the way you think it does.  That is, it is not a replace-string function.

It maps *individual characters* from one list to *the corresponding characters* in the other list.

So this,

```
translate(@href, ' ', '%20')
```

means, translate a space into `%`.  The `20` part of the third argument is ignored.