# XSLT replace double quotes in variable

Tags: xml, json, xslt, xpath

Just to clarify, I am using XSLT 1.0. Sorry for not specifying that at first.

I have an XSLT stylesheet where I'd like to replace double quotes with something safe that's safe to go into a JSON string. I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/message">
    <xsl:variable name="body"><xsl:value-of select="body"/></xsl:variable>


    {
      "message" : 
      {
        "body":  "<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($body)"/>"
      }
    }
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I have XML passed in that looks like the following, this will always work just fine:

```
<message>
 <body>This is a normal string that will not give you any issues</body>
</message>
```

However, I'm dealing with a body that has full blown HTML in it, which isn't an issue because `normalize-space()` will take care of the HTML, but not double quotes. This breaks me:

```
<message>
<body>And so he quoted: "I will break him". The end.</body>
</message>
```

I really don't care if the double quotes are HTML escaped or prefixed with a backslash. I just need to make sure the end result passes a JSON parser.

This output passes JSON Lint and would be an appropriate solution (backslashing the quotes):

```
{ "body" : "And so he quoted: \"I will break him\". The end." }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a recursive template, you can perform the replace. This example replaces `"` with `\"`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/message">
        <xsl:variable name="escaped-body">
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="body"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&quot;'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'\&quot;'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>


        {
        "message" : 
        {
        "body":  "<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($escaped-body)"/>"
        }
        }
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="replace-string">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace"/>
        <xsl:param name="with"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text"
                        select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And produces the output:

```
{
"message" : 
{
"body":  "And so he quoted: \"I will break him\". The end."
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of XSLT?  Keep in mind that many characters require special escaping in [JSON](http://json.org/).  While this is technically possible in XSLT, it won't be pretty.

If you really just care about the backslash, though, and you're using XSLT 1.0, any of the various [string replace templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3067130/4525) should do it for you.