# XSLT Regex Replace Function

Tags: regex, xslt, hl7, mirth

We've been pulling our hair out just trying to just trying to get a basic example of the XSLT replace function to work.

**I'm leaving this text in tact for context, but you may want to skip to the update**

We're using [Mirth](http://www.mirthcorp.com/) to pull in HL7 messages.  We're unsure whether this supports XSLT version 2, but we believe it uses SAXON - http://saxon.sourceforge.net/, which purportedly does support XSLT2 and hence the replace function.

In any case, we tried using [XSLTCake](http://www.xsltcake.com/) to try and get even a demo replacement to work, to no avail. We've seen this either referenced as `replace` or `fn:replace` as well as a couple other suggestions using other libraries.

If XSLT2 isn't supported by [Mirth](http://www.mirthcorp.com/), we would need a workaround for XSLT1.  We found one here:  [XSLT string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067113/xslt-string-replace) -  but have been unable to get this to work either.

This is a tough to get down to a single question as I'm asking alot, but here goes... Can anyone provide a working example of performing a regex replacement in an XSLT? Preferably one that will run in an online parser for reference.

Here's a [sample](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/zddkj9) - which apparently should work.[1](http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/45627-how-use-replace-function-xslt-2-0-a.html)

**Update**

Thanks to Michael Kay for providing code below to determine XSLT version.

```
<!--Transformed using 1.0 provided by Apache Software Foundation (Xalan XSLTC)-->
```

So It turns out we were all wrong about Mirth using SAXON and hence supporting XSLT2. I'll update with our attempt at implementing the version 1 workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find out which XSLT processor you are using. This is straightforward: insert this

```
<xsl:comment>Transformed using <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/> provided by <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/></xsl:comment>
```

into your stylesheet to output a comment in your result document.

Once you know what programming language you are using, you can start thinking about writing code.

Comment: Thanks for that, that'll be why we couldn't get most of it to work! Updating.

Comment: There appear to be people who have been successful in swapping in Saxon in place of Xalan within Mirth, see for example http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=952