# XSLT param returns incorrect value in javascript block

Tags: javascript, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am passing param value as directory say c:\MyFolder\myfile.txt.

But when I receive that value in javascript block it returns value c:MyFolderMyfile.txt

How will I get same param value in javascript block?

Code:

```
<xsl:param name="ResourcePath"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
           alert('<xsl:value-of select="$ResourcePath"/>');
           //It shows value c:MyFolderMyfile.txt but I want c:\MyFolder\myfile.txt
        </script>
      </head>
      <body> </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work in JavaScript, instead of outputting this...

```
alert('c:\MyFolder\myfile.txt');
```

You need to output this

```
alert('c:\\MyFolder\\myfile.txt');
```

Unfortunately XSLT 1.0 does not have a "replace" function, so you will have to use a recursive template to replace `\` with `\\`.

A quick search on StackOverflow finds this as an example:

[XSLT string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067113/xslt-string-replace)

Try this XSLT, which incorporates the "replace" template

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:param name="ResourcePath" select="'c:\MyFolder\myfile.txt'"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head>    
         <script type="text/javascript">
            <xsl:text>alert('</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
               <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$ResourcePath" />
               <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'\'" />
               <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'\\'" />
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text>');</xsl:text>
         </script>
       </head>
       <body> </body>
     </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
     <xsl:param name="text" />
     <xsl:param name="replace" />
     <xsl:param name="by" />
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
         <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
         <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
           <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
           <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
           <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
         </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">alert('c:\\MyFolder\\myfile.txt');</script>
   </head>
   <body/>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your slashes in `$ResourcePath`. Replace the text there: `c:\MyFolder\myfile.txt` with: `c:\\MyFolder\\myfile.txt`.

JavaScript interprets the `\` in the string as an escape character. Since the slash is followed by a `m`, which results in a invalid escape sequence, it just renders the `m` instead of `\m`.

Comment: Cerbus,How will I get expected result

Comment: What do you mean? If you escape the slashes in your resource, it will show single slashes in the JavaScript string.

Comment: No, As per I explained above.I am sending value with single slash. And in javascript, I am getting string value without any slash. and I want it with single slash

Comment: The problem is that JavaScript is receiving values with single slashes. You need to change that before it's sent to JS.