# Removing double quotes in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using XSL 1.0, I have this kind of XML-

```
<ID>"7080"</ID>
<NAME>"Media"</NAME>
<ADDRESS>
    <STREET_1>"400 Street"</STREET_1>
</ADDRESS>
```

The values are coming with Double Quotes. I am trying to remove these double quotes in XSL 1.0 and show up my Result as:

```
 <ID>7080</ID>
    <NAME>Media</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>
        <STREET_1>400 Street</STREET_1>
    </ADDRESS>
```

Also, I have tried it to apply translate function to the root element of the XML but it isn't working. 
Any suggestion would help!

Comment: Can you post your XSLT that you've tried?

Comment: you can use string replace to do. Use these links [xslt-string-replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067113/xslt-string-replace) [String Replace](http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx)

Comment: And what would you like to do if you've an element like: `<ID>"70"80"</ID>` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `translate` to replace the (escaped) double quote with an empty char.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '\&quot;', '')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When used with the identity transform above and a shoutcase `XML` root element wrapper, this returns:

```
<XML>
    <ID>7080</ID>
    <NAME>Media</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>
        <STREET_1>400 Street</STREET_1>
    </ADDRESS>
</XML>
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart for the template. It worked very well with the complete XML. I additionally worked for the attributes also like this : <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:for-each select="@*">    
    <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}"><xsl:value-of select="translate(.,$Quotation_Mark, $Empty)"/></xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>