# Combine the value of XML tags on an XSLT table with a link via JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I have a table in an .xsl file with the following:

```
<table>
<xsl:for-each select="xmlfile/example">
<tr class="clickable">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="example_name"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

I want the table rows to open a tab/window with a Google search query, with the value of "example_name" added to the link via JQuery; something like this, but where it actually works:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
  window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + "<xsl:value-of select="example_name"/>");
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call into XSLT from JavaScript or call JavaScript from XSLT like in your example click handler (*). If you're using XSLT on the server-side, what's wrong with using

```
<td><a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('https://www.google.com/search?q=', example_name)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="example_name"/>
</a></td>
```

If you absolutely must use JavaScript to open a new window, you'll be getting yourself into trouble because of too many levels of nested quoting. Eg.

```
<td><a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <!-- INVALID XML ATTRIBUTE SPECIFICATION
         just for demonstrating the problem with nesting single quotes
         into single quoted literals into double quoted attributes -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('javascript:window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=", example_name)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="example_name"/>
</a></td>
```

See [Removing double quotes and slashes in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476659/removing-double-quotes-and-slashes-in-xslt/50484170#50484170) for a technique to help here.

*) There used to be EXSLT many years ago which allowed XSLT to be extended by JavaScript custom functions, though it never ran in the browser. There was also the Sarissa project (like in 2006 or so) to bring XSLT to browsers, in addition to what has been possible with `<?xml-stylesheet>` and browser-specific ways to invoke XSLT processing. And I believe Saxonica's newest XSLT engine has been demonstrated to run browser-side as well, and also has integration facilities such as JSON parsing for use within such kind of environment.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<table>
<xsl:for-each select="xmlfile/example">
<tr class="clickable" data-query="{example_name}">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="example_name"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

and then

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
  window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + $(this).data('query'));
});
```