# Remove characters using xslt

Tags: xml, string, xslt

I need to remove the following characters from a string value using xsl 1.0:

```
`, / *` and break line (**<br>**)
```

I have come up with the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(//string/string/string/string, translate(//string/string/string/string, ',/*<br>'" ', ''), '')" />
```

But it's not working well, what or where should I look to change?
Thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific rather than just saying "It's not working well"? i.e Are you getting an error message? Ideally you should show a sample of your input XML, a sample of your expected output, and the output you are actually getting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly always break down problems into smaller subsets.

the function translate is basically a character-level operation. as such it is not suitable for the `<br>` part of the solution.  Also note that <  and > are special characters in xsl/xml.

Thus, assuming `//string/string/string/string` IS the correct XPath here..

```
translate(//string/string/string/string, ',/*','   '):
```

Should be sufficient to remove the , and / and * characters

As for `<br>`, well ideally you'd want to use a replace function, which does not exist in xslt 1.0.  Take a look at this question for an example of a template which does the job if you are in xslt 1: [XSLT string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067113/xslt-string-replace)

you could also consider if xslt is the right tool for the job here, but that depends on the wider context.

Comment: If the characters in the second argument to `translate` are to be removed then the third argument should be an empty string `''` and not `'   '` as that would replace the characters with a blank.

Comment: Perhaps you could say more explicitly that an unescaped `<br>` cannot be part of a string in XML? And, by extension, that using regexes to find and remove elements is a bad idea?