# How to force escaping of every double quote " into the XML character entity &quot;

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping, xslt-1.0, soa

How can I transform all `"`  present in a string to `&quot;` ?

Example:

**Source Data:** `<String>"ACCOUNT_DETAILS" : "75"</String>`

**Target Data:** `<String>&quot;ACCOUNT_DETAILS&quot; : &quot;75&quot;</String>`

PS: I am using XSLT 1.0. I tried discussion at "[XSLT string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067113/xslt-string-replace)" but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to do such a thing? From an XML perspective, `&quot;` is *exactly the same as* `"`. And any XSLT processor (or XML library for that matter) will properly escape the single and double quotes when they appear as literals inside an attribute, which is generally the only place where they need escaping as `&apos;` and `&quot;` respectively.

However, if there is some odd requirement that you **must** do so (there's a lot of tools out there that only support XML partially, or some variant thereof) you can do the following:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
```

Which will output `&quot;`. Note that a processor is not required to support `disable-output-escaping`, that even if it does, it does not have to obey, and that from XSLT 2.0 onwards, you should use `xsl:character-map` instead, which is a much better and more flexible alternative.

## With a string-replacement template for XSLT 1.0

The question you may have followed up with is how to apply this technique for the whole string. Since XSLT 1.0 does not have a good string search and replace function, you have to use recursive call-templates. For the exercise (I'm a bit rusty with XSLT 1.0 and usually use XSLT 2.0 or higher, in which this is a one-liner), I thought I'd try it again for old-times sake.

This works with your input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="input">"ACCOUNT_DETAILS" : "75"</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="result">
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$input"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="search" select="'&quot;'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="'&amp;quot;'" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$result" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="replace">
        <xsl:param name="string" />
        <xsl:param name="search" />
        <xsl:param name="replace-with" />        
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($string, $search)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $search)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$replace-with" />
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $search)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="search" select="$search" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="$replace-with" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and outputs:

```
&quot;ACCOUNT_DETAILS&quot; : &quot;75&quot;
```

### Edit: using JSON escapes `\"`

In the comments you wrote that you required this for JSON. It is probably easier to use JSON escapes, because they have no special meaning in XML.

Take my code above and call it as follows, and remove the `disable-output-escaping`:

```
<xsl:call-template name="replace">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$input"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="search" select="'&quot;'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="'\&quot;'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Alternatively, if you want the XML-style escapes, instead of literally writing `&quot;` to the output stream (which is just another way of writing `"` and will be interpreted as such by any XML parser) you can double-escape the quotes by using the same code above, but without the `disable-output-escaping`. Then the literal XML will contain `&amp;quot` and your browser or XML parser will see it as `&quot;` (after unescaping).

Comment: Thanks Abel for the quick reply.
1. I tried your solution. On testing, the output is as: `"ACCOUNT_DETAILS" : "75"` . Looks like, XSLT processor converted it back into normal form, as stated by you earlier. I am using JDeveloper 12.1.3.0 for the operation.

2. I am working on exposing JSON output, from pl/sql, as rest service. In that case, all `"` in JSON output gets converted to `\"` when exposed as rest service. So, I thought converting `"` to `&quot;` may help. There is another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32699438/4741215) that I had raised for this issue.

Comment: @NameetNayan, then it is probably better to (1) use an XSLT 3.0 processor, which has native JSON support (you are on Java, shouldn't be hard to find Saxon) and to (2) if you don't/can't, escape to `\"`. I doubt the XSLT is "converting them back", I assume you are viewing it in a browser, which will interpret `&quot;` as `"`. If you want the browser to display as `&quot;`, simply remove the `disable-output-escaping` from the code, it will give you `&amp;quot;`, which will "look like" `&quot;`. Though I recommend to simply change the above code to replace to the JSON escape `\"`.

Comment: @NameetNayan, I have updated the answer to show how you can use the same code with JSON escapes, or how you can double-escape using the XML escapes.

Comment: Abel, I forgot to thank you for editing Heading to more meaningful one. :) [1] I tried your first solution at _http://xsltransform.net/_ and it is working fine over there. Not sure, the issue might be with the JDeveloper IDE I am using. [2] Regarding `<xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="'\&quot;'" />` , It replaces all " with \" upon execution. I think, I might not have clarified the question properly as It was not what I was looking for. With this, the final output from rest service comes as `\\\"ACCOUNT_DETAILS\\\" : \\\"75\\\"`.

Comment: @nameet, if result you see had three backslashes, then after transform you're doing something extra. Same with the disappearing quot, are you sure your directly transforming to disk and not a string of stream that gets send to the browser? Because there can be a lot of extra processing and escaping involved.

Comment: @nameet,or do you mean to say you *want* triple backslashes? Because then just change the replace string. In fact, you can use anything there and experiment yourself.

Comment: Abel, [1] Yes. After transform, there is extra processing. It does get send to the browser. Since, I am using OSB to send it as restful to browser and I am still new to OSB, I can't say for sure why it is happening. [2] No, I don't want triple backslashes. The extra Backslash appears after the transform has executed. [3] I tried passing the original output i.e. `\"ACCOUNT_DETAILS\" : \"75\"` to my Javascript code. Javascript seems to have auto-omitted all \ from rest service output. So, for the current work I am into, I don't need to transform `"` into `&quot;`.

Comment: @nameet, there are many ways escaping can be done and each language has its own method. Glad it works now.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be possible in XSLT 2.0 using a character map: http://xsltransform.net/pPzifoT/1. With XSLT 1.0 you can use a named template that replaces the double quote with `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&quot;]]></xsl:text>`.