# How to call a custom replace function twice in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I need to convert an input string -

```
10:05:30.00
```

to

```
10053000
```

that is to replace the ":" and the "." characters.

I referred to this answer - [XSLT string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067113/xslt-string-replace)

and added the replace function.

Now I can call it once like this -

```
<xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="fruits/apples"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="':'" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="with" select="''"/>
                          </xsl:call-template>
```

and it returns this value -

```
100530.00
```

How can I call it again where I can specify my replace string as  "." so that this character is removed. Please note I have to use XSLT 1.0 so I don't have access to the replace() function in XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you do simply:

```
translate ($string, ':.', '')
```

---

To actually replace multiple substrings (with more than one character each), your recursive template would have to do **two** nested loops - with the outer loop *tokenizing* the `search-strings` and/or the `replace-strings` parameter.