# xslt string replace concrete example

Tags: xslt-1.0

I've found the template Codesling has provided as a substitute to the replace-function in XSLT 1.0: [XSLT string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067113/xslt-string-replace)

The problem I'm having is that I cannot figure out how to adapt it to my concrete example, so I'm hoping for some pointers here.

I've got a xml-parameter called ./bib-info that looks like this (for example):

```
<bib-info>Gäbler, René, 1971-  [(DE-588)138691134]:                           Schnell-Umstieg auf Office 2010, [2010]</bib-info>
```

My goal is to replace the blanks between the "]:" and the beginning of the following text (in this case "Schnell"). The number of blanks is always the same btw.

Here are two other examples:

```
<bib-info>Decker, Karl-Heinz, 1948-2010  [(DE-588)141218622]:                           Funktion, Gestaltung und Berechnung, 1963</bib-info>

<bib-info>Decker, Karl-Heinz, 1948-2010  [(DE-588)141218622]:                           Maschinenelemente, 1963</bib-info>
```

Could anybody please give me a hint how to write the calling code

```
<xsl:variable name="newtext">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="a" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="b" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

so that it matches my problem?

Thanks in advance

Kate

Comment: **1.** You want to replace the blanks with what?  -- **2.** For a concrete example, we need to se where `<bib-info>` is relative to your current context. So please show us a [mcve].

Comment: You're so right of course! I want to replace the multitude of blanks with a single one so that the example `code` <bib-info>Decker, Karl-Heinz, 1948-2010  [(DE-588)141218622]:                           Funktion, Gestaltung und Berechnung, 1963</bib-info> `code`

Comment: Sorry - wasn't fast enough editing my comment... :-( I want to replace the multitude of blanks with a single one so that the ugly gap after the "]:" is closed. Excuse me for forgetting to mentioning that.

Comment: Could you not simply apply `normalize-space()` to the `bib-info` elements? Note that this would reduce *any* group of whitespace characters to a single space - in your example, it would change `1971-  [` to `1971- [`.

Comment: I'll have a look at the normalize-space() function - perhaps it'll solve my problem. Thanks for the tip! :-)

Comment: I've had a look at the normalize-space()-function and found that it does too much for my liking. I need the line-breaks to stay in the <bib-info>-construct so I cannot use this function. :-(

Comment: I don't see any line breaks in the examples you have provided.

Comment: You're right again, of course. But since the parameter <bib-info> is supposed to contain more or less formatted bibliographical information from a library catalog, I cannot rule out for certain that there won't be intended line breaks inside the <bib-info>-parameter. So using the normalize-space()-function would be nice to get rid of the excess blanks but would also kill off possible intended line-breaks in the process which would be bad.

Comment: Okay, so use a replace template like you started to (this is assuming the number of spaces in the block you want to remove is constant). -- P.S. I think you mean an *element*, not a *parameter*.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to replace the blanks between the "]:" and the beginning of the following text

An example doing this is the following:

```
<xsl:template match="bib-info">
  <xsl:variable name="newtext">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text()" />
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="']:                           '" />
      <xsl:with-param name="by" select="']: '" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <bib-info><xsl:value-of select="$newtext" /></bib-info>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this only replaces *real* spaces and not tabs or other special characters.

---

BTW replacing strings may not be the best choice in this case. You can achieve the same with the `substring` functions of XSLT-1.0:

```
<xsl:template match="bib-info">
  <xsl:variable name="newtext1" select="substring-before(text(),']:                           ')" />
  <xsl:variable name="newtext2" select="substring-after(text(),']:                           ')" />
  <xsl:variable name="newtext" select="concat($newtext1,']: ',$newtext2)" />
  <bib-info><xsl:value-of select="$newtext" /></bib-info>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is the same for both templates.