# How to replace a special character with a word/string in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to replace a single `/` with the word, `and`.
This is what I have now:

**Code:**

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

!-- identity transform -->

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">

    <xsl:copy>
        xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

!-- exception -->
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Category']/@CleanName">
    <xsl:attribute name="CleanName">
           <xsl:value-of select="translate('Cd /dvd inlays', '/ ', 'and')" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

**Input:**

```
<Category ID="129" CleanName="Cd /dvd inlays"></Category>
```

Output:

```
"Cdnadvdninlays"
```

Giving:

```
"Cd /dvd inlays"
```

Needed:

```
"cd and dvd inlays"
```

Comment: Please mark up your code as code using backticks. Some more context might also help.

Comment: updated and waiting for a comment

Answer (score 2):

[**`translate()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate) replaces single characters with single characters, not single characters with strings.  In your case, you're replacing `/` with `a` and SPACE with `n` – not what you want.

You want `replace()` instead.  Unfortunately, `replace()` requires XSLT 2.0.  For replace functionality in XSLT 1.0, see [XSLT string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3067113/290085).

Comment: can you give me an example what it should be?

Comment: No, I've given you everything you need. If you want further help, ***after having actually tried to apply this***, then follow-up with a request for a *specific* clarification.  Thanks.