# XmlSerializer breaks on .Net 5 upgrade

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, .net-5

We have a set of classes which we obtained via `xsd.exe` and we use to serialize/deserialize some XML. We were using this on .NET 4.7.2 and everything went well. Once we tried to upgrade to .NET 5, some is working ok but other classes are failing on the XMLSerializer constructor with the following error:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported
```

I've searched for this error but I only got results regarding WCF. Does anyone know if something might have changed in XMLSerializer that can provoke this error?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: I'll try to come up with a reproduced example as I cannot share the code.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201877/platformnotsupportedexception-xslcompiledtransform-loadxslt-not-loading-the). If you have a xlst using a javascript or C# code for transformation, that may be the issue.

Comment: Ok. I found the problem. It looks as if some property had a different type in the attribute than  in the property itsel (DateTime vs DateTime?). The weird thing is that this worked and now it does not...

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I leave the answer here for if it helps someone. We had a property like this:

```cs
/// <remarks/>
[XmlElement("EstimatedEndDateTime", typeof(System.DateTime), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
[XmlElement("FinalizedEndDateTime", typeof(System.DateTime), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
[XmlChoiceIdentifier("ItemElementName")]
public System.DateTime? Item
{
    get
    {
        return this.itemField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.itemField = value;
    }
}
```

I had to change the type in the `XmlElement` attributes to be also `System.DateTime?`. The weird thing is that it used to work with .Net 4.7.2.

Comment: The same root cause as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60976792/net-core-3-1-soap-platform-not-supported-error-compiling-jscript-csharp-script
Looks like the rules are now strict.

Comment: Indeed it helped us too. In our case the xsd translates into a c# property with array of array [][]. After generating the clases we need to replace every instance of [][] into [].
HTH someelse too.

Comment: @pposada I had the same, did it had any further consequenses for your application? since you change a two dimentional array to a one dimentional. Or did everying worked as expected?