# handle nested elements while converting XML to JSON using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt, nested

I have a use-case where i have convert the below xml to json:-

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<event:Event>
<event:Order>
 
  <ns2:Date>2021-01-25T05:15:27.639Z</ns2:Date>
  
  <ns2:AdditionalDataList>

      <ns2:AdditionalData 
        content="123" 
        id="456" 
        isflag="true" 
        namespace="blahblah"/>
      <ns2:AdditionalData 
        content="blah1-{&quot;blah2&quot;:{&quot;blah3&quot;:&quot;blah4&quot;},&quot;blah5&quot;:{&quot;blah6&quot;:&quot;blah7&quot;},&quot;blah8&quot;:{&quot;blah9&quot;:&quot;blah10&quot;},&quot;blah11&quot;:{&quot;blah12&quot;:&quot;blah13&quot;},&quot;blah14&quot;:&quot;blah15&quot;,&quot;blah16&quot;:&quot;blah17&quot;}" 
        id="678" 
        isflag="true" 
        namespace="blahblah"/>
      <ns2:AdditionalData 
        content="1238721893721" 
        id="900" 
        isflag="true" 
        namespace="blahblah"/>
  
  </ns2:AdditionalDataList>
</event:Order>
</event:Event>
```

I am using a generic XSLT to convert the above xml to json

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
 
    <xsl:template match="/*[node()]">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="detect" />
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
 
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="detect">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current()) and name(following-sibling::*[1]) != name(current())">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*[name() != name(current())]) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current())">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
                    <xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*) = name(current())">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][name() = name(current())]">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>" : [</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" /><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) > 0 or count(@*) > 0">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) = 0">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:apply-templates select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
 
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="obj-content">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="attr" />
            <xsl:if test="count(@*) &gt; 0 and (count(child::*) &gt; 0 or text())">, </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" mode="detect" />
            <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and not(@*)">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and @*">
                <xsl:text>"text" : "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">, </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
 
    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="attr">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
 
    <xsl:template match="node/@TEXT | text()" name="removeBreaks">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '&#xA;'))"><xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($pText, '&#xD;&#xA;'), ' ')"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="removeBreaks">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&#xD;&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT is not working as the resulting json is invalid because of the nested content value under   ns2:AdditionalDataList and is throwing the below error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 94:
...: "blah1-{"                    blah2 ":{"  
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'
```

Can you advise on what could we modify in the XSLT to handle nested cases like this ?

Comment: Your input XML is not well formed as `event` and `ns2` prefixes are not defined.

Comment: You will need to escape the double quotes inside text values. Use backslash, `\"`, and the [text/replace template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3067130/1422451).